# The tar might be corrupted or it is compressed in an unexpected way

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to unpack `tar.xz` file using gradle. First I download it and then unpack using tasks

```
def rootDir = project(":").projectDir

task downloadGHC(type: Download) {
    src "$ghcDownloadLink"
    dest new File("$rootDir/applications/install", "ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz")
    onlyIfNewer true
}

task unpackGHC(dependsOn: downloadGHC, type: Copy) {
    from tarTree(downloadGHC.dest)
    into "$rootDir/applications/ghc"
}
```

But I get this error

```
Unable to expand TAR 'L:\...\applications\install\ghc-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz'
  The tar might be corrupted or it is compressed in an unexpected way.
  By default the tar tree tries to guess the compression based on the file extension.
  If you need to specify the compression explicitly please refer to the DSL reference.
> Error detected parsing the header
```

I am able to open the file so it is not corrupted. How to unpack it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is an error parsing the header, I suppose the `tarTree()` accepts only `.tar` files and not `.tar.xz` file. You can call an external program like `tar` from your gradle script to unpack the file.
Or you can write a small program to decompress the xz to tar using [xz-java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html) library (XZInputStream class).

Comment: hm...So I have to provide another application to unpack archive. Too bad.

Comment: answer updated: try xz-java if you do not have tar installed.